# Second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to solve (in parametric fashion and NOT numerically) the following nonlinear second-order ODE.

$\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle m}w'' = A + B - C^2 \frac{\displaystyle (w'-n)}{\displaystyle(C-G)(w'-n)+mw} + \frac{\displaystyle2C(w'-n)}{\displaystyle m}$

where $A,B,C,n,m,G$ are constants.

I did try to parse the expression for the second-order ODE in Matlab LiveScript utilizing MUPAD in the background. Is it possible to provide a format that can be parsed efficiently in MUPAD? I am new to solving ODEs with software and I do not understand what the problem might be. I give the outline of the code:

```
syms A B C G m n
syms w(t)
diff_equation = 1/m * diff(w(t), t, 2) - A - B + (C^2 * (diff(w(t), t) - n))/((C - G) * (diff(w(t), t) - n) - mw) - (2 * C * (diff(w(t), t) - n))/m
syms v0 w0
init_condition = {w(sym(0)) == w0, subs(diff(w(t), t), t, sym(0)) == v0}
aux1 = unique([diff_equation, init_condition{:}]);
dsolve(symfun(aux1, symvar(w(t))))
```

If I remove the term $mw$ from the denominator of the first fraction that appears, then I can get a solution, otherwise, MUPAD cannot provide a parametric expression of the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi ! Indeed, if you remove $mw$ of the denominator then the equation simplifies to a linear one. Otherwise I cannot really help you as I don't know MUPAD.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by the denominator ?

Comment: What makes you think there is a 'nice' exact solution? As the equation is autonomous you might try reducing the order by the substitution $w'(t)=v(w)$. Also, is the "second order logic" tag a mistake?

Comment: @Sal I guess you were right about the tab, so I removed it. I don't know if there is an exact solution. This is what I am investigating right now. Is there any reference that someone could suggest on how to solve this issue?

I did try the substitution $w'(t) = v(w)$ which ends up in a system of two ODES but again MUPAD cannot solve it.

Comment: @Theleb what do you mean by multiplying by the denominator? You mean multiply the left hand side and the right hand side by the denominator $\displaystyle (C-G)(w'-n) + mw$

Comment: Exactly, I didn't try it out though but it might give somewhat of a nicer form for the equation

Comment: @Theleb I did multiply both sides with the denominator, but when I parse it into MUPAD, again it cannot solve it. It might be an instance, that does not have analytic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this system will have closed form solutions only for very specific values of the constants. You can consider the original system
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{m}\frac{dz}{dt} &= A + B - C^2\frac{(z-n)}{(C-G)(z-n) + mw} + 2C(z-n)/m\\
\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dt} &= z
\end{align}
and try to find first integrals for it. Dividing the second equation by the first you will get, after some simplifications:
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dz} &= \frac{mzw-P_1(z)}{P_2(z)w+P_3(z)},\\
\end{align}
where $P_i$ are polynomials with $deg(P_1)=2$, $deg(P_2)=1$ and $deg(P_3)=2$.
By making the substitution $$w=\frac{1}{f(z)}-\frac{P_3(z)}{P_2(z)}$$
you find
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{df}{dz} &= R_1(z)f^3+R_2(z)f^2,\\
\end{align}
where $R_1(z)$ and $R_2(z)$ are rational functions. This is a [Abel equation of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind). For some values of parameters this equation can be made separable, Bernoulli, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Diego for your answer, however I want to keep it as clean as possible, since this is merely a single case for my work and then I need to obtain several other quantities (such as the derivative of the solution that we are seeking right now, so it will get quite messy). Can you suggest something else, from which I can get a clean closed-form expression of the solution (again my aim is not to solve it numerically)? Or something, that I can put into MUPAD and obtain a parametric expression?

Thank you.